# I have a significant change in my outcome with the opposite sign in the lead period. Is this an issue?

Tags: regression-coefficients, standard-deviation, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, lags

Suppose I have a negative significant effect of a variable x on y. Also negative significant effect of the lag ie variable L1.x on y . But I get a positive sign significant effect on y in the future period ie lead1.x.Is it always the case there is something wrong with my identification?